# Centralize millions of records from 1000+ DBs

Tags: .net, database, postgresql, synchronization, bigdata

We have 1500+ Local Servers, where we use a PostgreSQL DB where we store some sales transactions data.
Each local server, would add daily about 200+ records, so that's about 300.000 daily records (between 8AM - 10PM).

We would need to store each transaction for at least 18 months, so that means that the data could reach 167.000.000 records.

Now, we have a request to analyze these transactions, and we were thinking about developing a centralized solution so that we can do some BI on it.

What would be the best way to do this ?

In each local server, I would create a new table, that only holds a reference to a newly created transaction ID. I would use this additional table to find out every time, what's the newest transactions, that are yet to be synced. Once the sync is done, I would then delete the references, waiting for new ones to appear.

Then, I was thinking about developing a REST API with it's own Infrastructure, that holds the connection string to all those 1500+ DB Instances, and, from time to time, check every instance for "what's new" in the DB., to save the data centralized.

From there, I would develop a GUI for reporting.
Now, I would go cloud on this REST API (probably Azure), but, unfortunately i have never experienced searching through million of records, so this is something new for me.
Is CosmosDB a good solution to store this kind of data ?

Is there any other "best-approach" for this ?

Comment: wow, 1.5k clusters is an impressive figure. I heard that greenplum is the way to go for these kind of applications, but I never used it myself.

Comment: I think it would be better to use OLTP over RDBMS here. You can use outbox pattern or change data capture to feed the OLTP db.

Answer (score -1):

the problem with PG is that when you use several different databases from the same cluster or from different clusters the joins performed by the query will involve "remote joins" which are, neither more nor less, than the copy of the whole table remote into a temporary table to perform a nested loop type join. This is the worst case scenario for performance...

As far as BI goes, PostGreSQL is far from the best RDBMS for doing this. It is in my opinion the worst in terms of performance, just above SQL Lite!
Aggregation calculations of type COUNT or SUM... are some of the worst performance imaginable. To read :

[PostGreSQL vs Microsoft SQL Server – Comparison part 2 : COUNT performances](http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-microsoft-sql-server-comparison-part-2-count-performances/)
There is also the absence of certain technologies which make it possible to greatly accelerate the exploitation of large tables and large volumes of data:

- no compression
- no vertical indexes (columnstore for example...)
- no "in memory" tables
- embryonic parallelism
- performance-limited partitioning

For columstore indexes you can use the Fujistu version of PG, but it cost a lot...

So my recommendation is not to use PG for theases features. Choose another RDBMS, like Terradata, Oracle or MS SQL Server (which is less costly and performs better than Oracle)

Comment: Then how do you explain that we handle roughly 40 million INSERTs daily (up to 3000tps) and analysing complex data within milliseconds? (hard 90 millisecond threshold) On a single server, slightly older PostgreSQL version, version 12.

Comment: @frank_heikens 40 000 000 / (24 * 60 * 60) = 462.. ! So 40 millions of INSERTS a day is an average of 429 tps... Which is not a problem.

Comment: We don't do average, because the customers (about 5 million) aren't online during the night. And we also don't do just an INSERT, we receive data, INSERT this data, but also check a lot of statistics for all kinds of processes, all within 30 to 40 milliseconds. Something that you claim isn't possible in PostgreSQL. So why do you think that this isn't possible? We do this for over 10 years. None of the limitations that you mention, is an issue in real life.

Comment: But your are very far away from performances thats bigs RDBMS can do. Take a look over tpc.org. On simple transaction (TPC C - like what you do) the actual record is about 11 789 183 tps... https://www.tpc.org/tpcc/results/tpcc_perf_results5.asp?resulttype=nonclusterall

Comment: Ok, great, but my customer doesn't have more customers to generate load. Even if this database could handle 500 million tps, they would never reach that number in practice: Not enough customers (just ~ 5 million). Current load is 2000tps, typical for Friday afternoon. But even they would have 10 times more customers, that wouldn't be a problem at all, we would still be well below the 90ms threshold. But again, why do you claim that these numbers aren't possible with PostgreSQL?

Comment: @frank_heikens, Because PG lacks many features necessary to handle large volumes of data... In particular the one already mentioned in my answer, but also the weakness of its optimizer and the organizational structure of its MVCC which makes statistical calculations of the type SUM or COUNT extremely slow... To read me: http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-sql-server-mssql-part-3-very-extremely-detailed-comparison/

Comment: Just not true, we handle large volumes and are time constraint. No problem at all. I do understand that you have an opinion, but that’s very different from experience